# Normal and central subgroups of finite $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group where $|G| = p^k$ where $p$ is a prime and $k\gt 0$.  Prove that

1. $|Z(G)| \gt 1$; and
2. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p$, then $N$ is contained in $Z(G)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. I see that this is your first question. So I wanted to let you know a few things about MathSE. We like to know the sources of questions. We also like to know what you've tried on a problem or what your thoughts are, so that the answer does not re-invent the wheel. Also, many users find questions posted in the imperative ("Show that", "Prove", "Do") unpleasant and somewhat rude. These sort of pleasantries usually result in more and better answers. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Connie, could you please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For 1, use the Class Equation.

For 2, use the Class Equation (if $N$ is normal, then it must be a union of conjugacy classes; conjugacy classes have either order $1$, or order a power of $p$; but $N$ contains at least one conjugacy class of order $1$, hence...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I'd like to think about it, but it could be just a rewording of what has already been said. Using the orbit stabilizer theorem one can prove that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$ then $\#(X^G)\equiv \#(X)\text{ mod }p$ where $X^G$ denotes the set $\{x\in X:gx=x\text{ for all }g\in G\}$ of fix points.

So, let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $N\unlhd G$ be nontrivial. Let $G$ act on $N$ on by conjugation. By the above we see that $\#(N^G)\equiv |N|\text{ mod }p$. But, since $p\mid |N|$ (since it's a nontrivial subgroup of a finite $p$-group) this implies that $p\mid \#(N^G)$. But, write it out and see that $N^G=N\cap Z(G)$ and so this prove that $p\mid |N\cap Z(G)|$ for any nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, and so in particular, $N\cap Z(G)$ is nontrivial. Taking $N=Z(G)$ gives 1. immediately. It also gives 2. with a little thought, since we know that $p\mid |N\cap Z(G)|$ and $|N\cap Z(G)|\leqslant p$ we must have that $|N\cap Z(G)|=p$ and so clearly $N\cap Z(G)=N$ and so $N\subseteq Z(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the class equation. Since the order of $G$ is a prime power, all of its conjugacy classes are of prime power order. Remember that the center of the group consists entirely of the singleton conjugacy classes (the classes of size $1$). If the center was trivial, the class equation would be $1$ plus positive prime powers. So we would have $1+p(\mathrm{something})=p^k$. This implies that $1=0$ mod $p$ (contradiction). Therefore, the center must contain more than one element.

By a similar line of reasoning, a normal subgroup consists of entire conjugacy classes unioned together (since $N$ is closed under conjugation, if part of a conjugacy class is in $N$, then the whole class must be in $N$). Since conjugacy classes have prime power cardnalities, the identity is in $N$ (whose class has size 1), and $|N|=p$, we have that all of the remaining classes are prime powers smaller than $p$. Thus $N$ is the union of classes of size 1. These are precisely elements of the center.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [class equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class)? Define an action of the group on itself by conjugation:
$$G\times G\to G\,\,,\,\,g\cdot x:=x^g:=g^{-1}xg$$

Now, under this action, we get

$$\forall\,\,x\in G\,\,,\,\mathcal O(x):=\{x^g\;:\;g\in G\}\,\,,\,Stab(x):=\{g\in G\;:\;x^g=x\}=C_G(x)$$

Well, now just use the basic lemma $\,|\mathcal O(x)|=[G:Stab(x)]\,$ and , of course, the fact that $\,G\,$ is a $\,p-\,$group...