# To show if $O(G)=p^{n}$ then $Z(G)\neq \{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normal and central subgroups of finite $p$-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83841/normal-and-central-subgroups-of-finite-p-groups)

I want to show that if $O(G)=p^{n}$ then $Z(G)\neq \{e\}$, where $p$ is a prime number and $Z(G)=\{a\in G | ax=xa, \forall x\in G\}$, which is also known as a center of the group $G$.
I think I have to use the Lagrange theorem which state that in a finite group $G$, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $O(H)|O(G)$. But i don't get any right approach to use this to prove the given result.

Comment: See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83841/normal-and-central-subgroups-of-finite-p-groups).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.
$$
o(G) = o(Z(G)) + \sum_{C(a)\neq G} \frac {o(G)} {o(C(a))}
$$
where $C(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$.

Comment: Is this actually a class equation?

Comment: Well, this is known as *the* class equation (in group theory)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [class equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class)? Define an action of the group on itself by conjugation:
$$G\times G\to G\,\,,\,\,g\cdot x:=x^g:=g^{-1}xg$$

Now, under this action, we get

$$\forall\,\,x\in G\,\,,\,\mathcal O(x):=\{x^g\;:\;g\in G\}\,\,,\,Stab(x):=\{g\in G\;:\;x^g=x\}=C_G(x)$$

Well, now just use the basic lemma $\,|\mathcal O(x)|=[G:Stab(x)]\,$ and , of course, the fact that $\,G\,$ is a $\,p-\,$group...